# I have to modify batch file to read log file which is getting append everyday with date

Tags: batch-file

I have to modify batch file to read log file which is getting append everyday with date.

My requirement is that I have to read the log for current date and find some string in the log detail. A sample log file is as below.

```
c:\\> date /t
Tue 03/23/2015

Batch Summary 
------------------------
Total records = 11
Total records with error = 0
Batch filter ended 

c:\\> date /t
Tue 03/24/2015

Batch Summary 
------------------------
Total records = 11
Total records with error = 0
Batch filter ended "
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What string(s) do you want to find? And what do you want to do once they have been found?

Comment: I have to find "total records with error msg = 0" and "batch filter ended "  from current date and then i m printing the result of the current date's log into ".txt" file and emailing the result

Comment: can  we take for sure, that the file is strongly chronological (newest entry is always the last)?

Comment: Yes it will be always at last

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

If you're trying to get a timestamp, you could do `echo Timestamp[%date%, %time%] >> log.txt`. Since you'd be using `>>` instead of `>`, you would get every timestamp you requested in the log file instead of it being overwritten every time it's executed.

A sample output would be `Timestamp[2015-03-24, 20:37:31.86]`

Comment: I have to read log only for current date and I have to find "total records with error msg = 0" and "batch filter ended " from only current date log block  and then i m printing the result of the current date's log into ".txt" file and emailing the result

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
REM is there an entry for today?:
find "%date%" sample.log >nul
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :notfound

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('find "Total records with error" sample.log') do set tr=%%i
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('find "Batch filter ended" sample.log') do set bf=%%i

echo %tr%
echo %bf%
goto :eof
:notfound
echo sorry, no data for today.
```

Comment: FOR /F "eol=, tokens=1 delims=, " %%i in (%batchloghome%\%reqfilenamelist%) do (
 
color a
 
--@echo the log file screening now
 
--@echo %%i 
--@set logfilename=%%i
 
--@echo checking the variable 
--@echo Scanning for the String..processing 
--@echo %batchloghome%
 
color b
 
type "%batchloghome%\%%i" | find "Total Records with Errors= 0"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 call :NotOkay1

type "%batchloghome%\%%i" | find "Batch Filter Ended"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 call :NotOkay2
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 call :Okay  

)

"Total Records with Errors= 0"
Batch Filter Ended

Comment: above code i m currently using to find the those string from the log file which wasn't appending so log file had log details for only one day now its appending and i have to read the log for current date only.

Comment: that's exactly, what my code does: check if there is an entry for today and if yes, read the last values (must be those of today then, because it's strongly chronological.  The `set` in the `for`commands overwrites with each occurence, so in the end, it holds the last value.